# Parsing apache2 config using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, nokogiri

How can i parse `apache2` config file using `nokogiri` or any other xml parser? I've tried to parse the file using `Nokogiri::XML` the following way:

```
parsed = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("/home/user/config"))
```

That didn't help. When trying to inspect the object using `parsed.errors` i get the following:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found>]
```

Is there any gems or anything else to parse apache config, edit and save it?

**UPD:**

Here is my config file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/user/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gemset/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gemset/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gemset/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin user@localhost

    RailsEnv staging

DocumentRoot /path_to_project/public
    Alias /webdav /path_to_project/public/dir
    Alias /webdav-some-dir path_to_project/public/dir/another_dir

ServerSignature On
    <Directory path_to_project/public>

         AllowOverride all     
         Options -MultiViews  
     AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    </Directory>

<Location /webdav>
        DAV On
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "webdav"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/project_name/passwd.dav
    PassengerEnabled off
    Require globalAdministrator
    <Limit GET OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Require user username #valid-user
    </Limit>
    <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
        Require user username #globalAdministrator
    </Limit>
   </Location>
   <LocationMatch "/webdav/.+/.+/.+/.+/.+/.+">
    <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
        Require user username #valid-user
    </Limit>
   </LocationMatch> 

<Location /webdav-some-dir>
        DAV On
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "webdav"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/project_name/passwd.dav
    PassengerEnabled off
    Require globalAdministrator
    <Limit GET OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Require user username #valid-user
    </Limit>
    <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
        Require user username #valid-user
    </Limit>
   </Location>
   <LocationMatch "/webdav-some-dir/.+/.+/.+/.+/.+">
    <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
        Require user username #valid-user
    </Limit>
   </LocationMatch> 

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 4):

Apache config files are not valid XML. It has XML-like (most likely SGML-like) tags for grouping of options, but it's not in any way XML. Try the apache_config gem for parsing the config file; though it seems unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash.from_xml(File.open("/path/to/config", "r").read)
```

If this doesnt work you schould also post the content of the config file here....

Comment: Yeah like Kovensky said thats no valid XML so you cant treat it like xml. What is your goal?

Comment: Parse - edit - save. I've found a gem `treetop`. Trying to write a parser now.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? I think your app should not be concerned about the  apache setup it's running under...

Comment: I need to change configuration for some users to forbid or permit access to some webdav directories. I want to change config and perform graceful restart.